# file.choose() alternative to import file in flexdashboard rstudio when published on shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I have created a project where you can upload any file from your local computer and you get different graphs on selected variables(Bar graph,Line graph,Box plot etc)
My project is working on local computer software, but when i publish on shinyapps.io , it shows an error since it does not support read.csv(file.choose()) command.
Please help me with code that i can add, so that shinyapps.io would run my code, and everyone could upload their file on website and startData variable could store that csv file for further process.
Or making a Input button on my flexdashboard which will import file and give to my variable startData

````
---
#author: "Yatharth Garg"
title: "SARAL"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    social: menu
    source_code: embed
    #orientation: rows
    vertical_layout: scroll
    theme: united #cerulean
    logo: favicon-32x32.png
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(tidyverse)
library(forecast)
library(highcharter)
library(DT)

startData <-read.csv(file.choose()) 


GBChoices <- as.list(names(startData))
names(GBChoices) <- paste(names(startData),map(startData,~length(unique(.x))))

updateData <- reactive(
  startData %>% group_by(!!! rlang::syms(input$GB)) %>% summarise_if(is.numeric,sum,na.rm=T))

```

Sidebar {.sidebar}
=====================================

```{r}
selectInput(inputId = "GB",label = "Group By",choices = GBChoices)
selectInput(inputId = "Metric",label = "Metric",choices = names(select_if(startData,is.numeric)))
```



Bar Graph
===================================== 

Column
-------------------------------------
### Bar Graph
```{r}
renderPlot({
 updateData() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=!! rlang::sym(input$GB),y=!! rlang::sym(input$Metric),fill=!! rlang::sym(input$GB))) +
  geom_col()
})
```


### Table 
```{r}
renderDT(
  updateData(), rownames = F, extensions = 'Buttons', filter="top", editable=T,
  options = list(
    dom = 'Blfrtip',
    buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'),
    lengthMenu = list(c(10,50,100,-1),c(10,50,100,"All"))
  )
)
```


Line Graph
=====================================


Column
-------------------------------------
### Line Graph
```{r}
renderPlot({
 updateData() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=!! rlang::sym(input$GB),y=!! rlang::sym(input$Metric),fill=!! rlang::sym(input$GB))) +
  geom_line()
})
```

Heat Map
=====================================

Column
-------------------------------------
### bin2d Graph
```{r}
renderPlot({
 updateData() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=!! rlang::sym(input$GB),y=!! rlang::sym(input$Metric),fill=!! rlang::sym(input$GB))) +
  geom_bin2d()
})
```

Point & Smooth graph
=====================================

Column
-------------------------------------
### Point Graph
```{r}
renderPlot({
 updateData() %>% ggplot(aes(x=!! rlang::sym(input$GB),y=!! rlang::sym(input$Metric),fill=!! rlang::sym(input$GB))) +
  geom_jitter()
 
})
```

Column
-------------------------------------
### Smooth Graph
```{r}
renderPlot({
 updateData() %>% ggplot(aes(x=!! rlang::sym(input$GB),y=!! rlang::sym(input$Metric),fill=!! rlang::sym(input$GB))) +geom_point(shape=1) +
   geom_smooth()
})
```

BoxPlot
=====================================

Column
-------------------------------------
### BoxPLot 
```{r}
renderPlot({
 updateData() %>% ggplot(aes(x=!! rlang::sym(input$GB),y=!! rlang::sym(input$Metric),fill=!! rlang::sym(input$GB))) +
  geom_boxplot()
 
})
```
````

Please append your innovative code in my code and reply me back.
I need your help, please please help me with that.

Comment: Have you read this? https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/upload.html

Comment: Yes i have created input button using this document

Comment: library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  headerPanel(title = "Shiny File Upload Example"),
  sidebarLayout(
    fileInput("file","Upload the file"),
    h5("Max File size to upload is 5mb")
      ),
      mainPanel(
        tableOutput("input_file")
      )
  ))
shinyServer(function(input,output){
  
  output$input_file <- renderTable({
    
    inpu = input$file
    if(is.null(inpu)){
      return()
    }
    
  })
})

Comment: but i am unable to integrate this shiny app with flexdashboard

Comment: It might not be possible to apply it to the flexdashboard template.

Comment: Can you please help me with alternate option to file.choose() so shinyapps.io would prompt window for accepting and csv file.